# Excel COM-Add-in crash after deploying VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, vsto, add-in

I recently developed a Excel COM-addin in C# using VS2010 which uses a Web reference to a remote Web service and sends data to and from the service. Once this was finished as per therequirements I followed the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) to get it installed on multiple client computers.

After the msi gets built as per the specifications, I installed the add-in on an external computer.  After the installation completes successfully I try to launch excel and it crashes. On further investigation, I managed to get to the Windows Error report(WERInternalMetadata.xml) file that has this piece of code.

```
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
    <Parameter0>excel.exe</Parameter0>
    <Parameter1>14.0.6126.5003</Parameter1>
    <Parameter2>505b0834</Parameter2>
    <Parameter3>AddInTestExcel2007</Parameter3>
    <Parameter4>1.0.0.0</Parameter4>
    <Parameter5>53304e03</Parameter5>
    <Parameter6>42</Parameter6>
    <Parameter7>16</Parameter7>
    <Parameter8>System.NullReferenceException</Parameter8>
</ProblemSignatures>
```

When I debug my add-in on Visual Studio I dont get a NullReference Exception. Apart from this I have no other information on what is causing excel to crash. Could someone please help me interpret this?

**EDIT - AddIn StartUp code**

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}

private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

typically, an Excel Add-in can crash on start-up of Excel for following reasons:

1. there is code in the start-up of the add-in which is not try/catch
   encapsulated.
2. the start-up code expects config or web service urls which are not present in the expected files.
3. the code encountered different run time conditions (an actual deployed machine) vs. running it in a Visual Studio Environment with expected permissions/office installed/.net versions installed etc.

can you please check your start up code and look for possible exceptions by wrapping it in a generic try/catch block?

you can also post the snippet here and we can help identify as well.

p.s. the general recommendation is to keep start-up code to a minimum if not zero. this is because modern versions of office apps like outlook actually disable an add-in if the load time is more than a particular value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The start up code in my add-in is Zero. But my add-in makes use of an app.config since it makes use of a web service `ServiceReference1.SNLSoapClient dp1 = new ServiceReference1.SNLSoapClient("SNLSoap");`. Something tells me it could be this line. Between my previous post and this post I figured out I was referring to the Web service with a localhost URL which obviously failed when I tried to install the add-in on other computers. I changed the URL to have the full IP address but then it makes use of the end point address in the instantiation, part of the app.config

Comment: I am not explicitly packaging the app.config with the msi, is this a requirement?

Comment: are you using app.config file? if yes, it may not work properly at runtime since add-ins run under excel.exe context. if you're not using app.config, then of course, you don't need to package them.

Comment: Yes. Most definitely I am using the app.config. This is basically to ensure/override the default soap settings in VS for allowing large data transfers to and from my Web service. How do I make sure my app.config gets packaged along with my vsto prior to deployment? Or is there a work around for the app.config that I can use?

Comment: on the machine where the addin crashes, can you please verify if it is able to read the app config values? if it does, then we may be going down the wrong path.. (there have been vsto 4.0 sp1 changes that affect app.config consumption) we need to be sure.

Comment: How do I verify that? excel crashes as soon as my add-in gets deployed and excel is launched?

Comment: what's your ThisAddIn_Startup  code look like? try putting a try/catch around it.

Comment: I have added that to my question above under the edit section. It has zero code.

Comment: ok. can you please verify this issue? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2011/06/14/vsto-4-0-sp1-will-cause-a-vsto-addin-to-not-find-its-config-file.aspx